# Creating Circles(div) and appending it to div#canvas

Tags: javascript, geometry, appendchild

I am trying to create new circles as my pen hovers on window. 
I am having issues where I cannot add circles to the page. It just hovers around. How would i be able to modify my code to add circles as it hovers.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> JavaScript Environment: Project </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
        html, body {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }
        #canvas {
            background-color: yellow;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        .pen {
            position: absolute;
            background-color: lightblue;
            width: 10px;
            height: 10px;
            border-radius: 5px;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        window.onload = function() {
            function Circle(x, y) {
                this.x = x;
                this.y = y;
            }
            var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

            canvas.onmousedown = function() {
                mouseDown();
            };
            canvas.onmouseup = function() {
                mouseUp()
            };
            canvas.onmousemove = function() {
                mouseMove(event)
            };
            function mouseDown (){
                console.log ("mouse down");
            }
            function mouseUp (){
                console.log ("mouse up");
            }
            function mouseMove(e) {
                var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
                var pen = document.createElement("div");
                var x = e.clientX;
                var y = e.clientY;
                var coor = "Coordinates: (" + x + "," + y + ")";
                pen.setAttribute("class", "pen");
                pen.style.left = x + "px";
                pen.style.top = y + "px";
                document.getElementById("canvas").innerHTML = coor;
                canvas.appendChild(pen);
                addCircles(x, y);

                console.log("location @ " + x + " : " + y);

            }
            function addCircles(x, y) {
                var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
                var circle = document.createElement("div");
                circle.setAttribute("class", "pen");
                circle.style.left = x + "px";
                circle.style.top = y + "px";
                canvas.appendChild(circle);

            }
            canvas.addEventListener("mouseMove", mouseMove, false);
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the line                 `document.getElementById("canvas").innerHTML = coor;`

Try adding a span `<span id="canvasText"></span>` inside of your canvas div and then changing the above line to `document.getElementById("canvasText").innerHTML = coor;`.

As it stands, you "reset" the contents of the canvas every time the mouse moves, so the circles are instantly removed from it. Reset only the span inside the canvas to keep the circles around.

Comment: I see, Thank you for your help. It fixed the issues. :)